# submit text from "div contenteditable"

Tags: input, submit, contenteditable, insertonsubmit

I'm trying to find a working solution, but there is nothing useful at the moment. I have the following form:

```
<form id="searchform" action="/search" onsubmit="putText()">
<div class="section" >
<div class="edit"><div ContentEditable = "true" id="text"></div></div>
<div class="control" onclick="sbmt()"></div>
</div>
<input id="s" name="q" class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

with the following js:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit').keydown(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
         //debugger;
        $(this).blur().next().focus();
        return false;
      }
 });
 })
});


function ElementInit() {
  new SectionalElement({
    sectionalNodeClassName: 'section',
    controlNodeClassName: 'control',
    background: '#f4fa58'
  }, 'sectional_element');
  return true;
}

function putText() {
  document.getElementById('s').value = document.getElementById('text').textContent;  
  return true;
}

function sbmt() {
document.getElementById("searchform").submit();
}
```

(also I use jquery-1.8.3.js) 
The query should look like "mysite.com/search?q=".
All that I need is to use div class="control" as Submit button instead of simple input (just replace the input button with div). When I press input button everything is ok, but when I use DIV class="control" submision doesn't work - form submits, but without text of query. I can't use just input, because the submit div is part of third party api.

Thanx for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to submit the text within the #text div? And also where are you trying to submit it to?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to submit #text div content. I need to submit it as a search query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the data inside the #text div you could use jQuery to get the data from the div:

```
function sbmt() {
  var param = '';

  // jQuery
  param = $('#text').text();

  // or you could use pure javascript
  param = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

  // Now that you have these values you should add them to your form as an input
  // input fields are how you send data through forms to wherever you are posting them
  // build the input field
  param = "<input type='text' name'param1' value='" + param + "'/>";

  // append it to the form
  $('#searchform').append(param);

  // finally submit the form.
  document.getElementById("searchform").submit();
}
```

Then you will be able to access your submited parameter based on the `name` you assigned it in the input field (in this case **param1**)

Have a play-around with this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UBg3V/3/) if you want to workout what is happening.

Comment: Thanx! People told me that it is imposible)) But I believed that it could work some how =)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use form actions on non-form elements.  Use input elements instead.

Comment: But form submits by the div, I just need to grab a text from "contenteditable" field with ?q= .

Comment: That doesn't matter, forms are not designed to send all of the information nested within the form element tags, but rather the values specified within controls, and Divs are not a supported control type.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.1

Comment: he sure has reasons to ask, maybe he made a rich-text-editor in the DIV like me or whatever and needs a fallback for non-AJAX-submits. So I'd just recommend to copy the contents of the DIV to a input per JS just before submission and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

### contenteditable.coffee

```
$('[contenteditable_form]').on 'submit', (e) -> 
  $form = $ e.target
  $form.find("[data-hidden-input]").each (i, e) ->
    $contenteditable = $ e
    attr = $contenteditable.data('hiddenInput')

    hidden_input = $form.find "[#{attr}]"

    value = $contenteditable.html()

    $(hidden_input).val value
```

### example.html

```
<input class="hidden" hidden_description name="some_name" type="hidden"> 
<div contenteditable="true" data-hidden-input="hidden_description"></div>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/dapi/eb737f5a7a7461cb548e